# How do I set up XDMCP?

Tags: 11.04, remote-x-session

Numerous posts for adding XDMCP to Ubuntu server tell me that I just need to bring up the login screen settings and flip to the "Remote" tab and ...

The Login Screen Settings in 11.04 (natty) has no tabs.  How do I go about getting XDMCP to work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this doesn't fit for you, but did you consider using NX instead?

Like NoMachine: http://nomachine.com/

Comment: Actually yes, I just tried it yesterday and it works perfectly. Tried it both on Ubuntu and CentOS with great results. Thanks for the suggestion.

Still.  I expect XDMCP to be simple setup.